# One way Data transfer techniques between SQL server dbs except transnational replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-replication

I need to transfer data from one SQL server db to another SQL server db (limited tables) on different servers , I want to avoid transaction replication due to bad experiences already.

What are the alternate approaches to move data near real time in sql server.

Thanks.

Comment: *I want to avoid transaction replication due to bad experiences already*  --  Such as?  What are the problems you've faced so far?

Comment: top of list is disaster recovery.

Comment: That is a reason why you would want real time duplication, not one of the problems you have faced with transactional replication.

Comment: We have setup transaction replication already on production server, and once it failed and took hours to fix the problem and sync data back (1000 of Gbs), Another problem is migration of server, we need to setup replication again. currently i am looking for a solution like i just get the updated data from primary and insert into secondary, Primary database is not much write heavy so updated dataset would not be more than few hundred mbs, We may need to update few data in secondary db so transaction replication is not an option in that case.

Comment: So, you want us to pull other technologies together to build something that looks like, but is somehow different to, transactional replication, rather than realizing that transactional replication probably is the right solution and if you're having troubles making it work, you probably need some consultancy work to make it work well in your environment and situation?

Comment: All transactional / differential type replication has complications and issues, whether it's out of the box transactional replication or if its a custom triggers/queues/cdc/ssis solution. The problem with the custom solution is that it's even more difficult to maintain. If it wasn't limited tables I would suggest availability groups, but they do a full replica, although it's much simpler than transactional replication and much better suited to DR.

Comment: I just noticed you said "We may need to update few data in secondary db". Thats fine - native transactional replication still works, but you'll be in an even worse state of consistency when you start updating data in the secondary.